# Core-Data: how to save an object twice in one relationship

Tags: core-data, relationship

say i have NSManagedObject A, that has a many-to-many relationship to NSManagedObject B. 
I have one saved instance of A and B. (not yet related)

Now I want A to save the instance of B twice in its relationship, which is of course a set.
Though, since its a set it stores only one reference of B.

see: (not syntax checked)

```
NSArray *tmpArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: B1, B1, nil];
[A setB: [NSSet setWithArray: tmpArray]];
```

-> only one B is stored in that relationship..

Is it possible to keep track of both B's ?

Comment: TechZen is correct. 100% agree.

So the question is: what is the problem you are trying to solve, that makes you think you need to store the relationship between Objects A and B1 twice? If you can explain that, we may be able to suggest how you can achieve your goal another way.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this. Core Data is not maintaining an array but an object-graph.

An object-graph store the relationships between objects. Since each object is unique, it makes no sense to have a duplicate relationship because that conveys no information. Suppose you have an object `Person` instance `Jane` that has a `brothers` relationship which contains three objects, `Steve`,`John` and `Mike`. It would be logically nonsensical to have two relationships to `Steve` because the real Steve that the object models isn't Jane's brother twice. Even if Jane did have two brothers named Steve, they would still be seperate individuals requiring their own objects to represent them in the object-graph.

If you find yourself thinking you require duplicate relationships, then you've probably misunderstood something about how the object-graph works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and searched but could not find anything. Indeed I was thinking about the relationship incorrectly.

The app is arranging a bunch of `Items` on a `Board` in sequence with repeats.

EX. Do A, Do B, Do C, Do A again, Do D

I created a good old-fashioned join table with the `Item`, `Board` and board position called `BoardItemPositon`.

From the `Board` entity you can hide all of the join table messiness and get and set an array.

```
@implementation Board

@dynamic boardItems;

- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items{
    //the ordered set of links
    NSMutableOrderedSet *boardItemSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet new];
    int i = 1;
    for (Item *item in items) {
        BoardItemPosition *boardItemPosition = (BoardItemPosition *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"BoardItemPosition" 
                                                                                                  inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i++];
        [boardItemPosition setItemPosition:num];
        [boardItemPosition setItem:item];
        [boardItemSet addObject:boardItemPosition];
    }

    //delete the old links
    for (BoardItemPosition *boardItemPosition in [self boardItems]) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:boardItemPosition.objectID]];
    }

    //set the new links
    [self setBoardItems:boardItemSet];  
}

- (NSArray *)items{
    //pull out item and add to array
    NSMutableArray *itemArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (BoardItemPosition *boardItemPosition in [self boardItems]) {
        [itemArray addObject:[boardItemPosition item]];
    }
    return itemArray;
}
```